# Draggable HTML elements positioning BUG

Tags: javascript, html, css

OK, so I'm kinda new to HTML and javascript but, I worked out this code with A LOT of help from our good old friend google. I was very excited when I got it to work as I intended. Only now I'm stuck with a bug I can't explain (or fix for that matter):

I made a quick CodePen for reference (the links don't lead anywhere in this demo):
https://codepen.io/BraddaBear/pen/BaJXEPw

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <title>Thomas' Portfolio</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/console favicon.png">
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='style.css'>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="border">
    <div class="draggable" ondblclick="location.href='videos.html';">
      <div class="dragger"> <img src="img/windows95 folder icon.png" width="72" height="72"> <p>My Video's</p> </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="draggable" ondblclick="location.href='photography.html';">
      <div class="dragger"> <img src="img/picture frame icon.png" width="74" height="72"> <p>image.jpg</p> </div>
    </div>
    <script src='script.js'></script>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
    var x, y, target = null;

document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  var clickedDragger = false;
  for(var i = 0; e.path[i] !== document.body; i++) {
    if (e.path[i].classList.contains('dragger')) {
      clickedDragger = true;
    }
    else if (clickedDragger && e.path[i].classList.contains('draggable')) {
      target = e.path[i];
      target.classList.add('dragging');
      x = e.clientX - target.style.left.slice(0, -2);
      y = e.clientY - target.style.top.slice(0, -2);
      return;
    }
  }
});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
  if (target !== null) target.classList.remove('dragging');
  target = null;
});

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  if (target === null) return;
  target.style.left = e.clientX - x + 'px';
  target.style.top = e.clientY - y + 'px';
  var pRect = target.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
  var tgtRect = target.getBoundingClientRect();

  if (tgtRect.left < pRect.left) target.style.left = 0;
  if (tgtRect.top < pRect.top) target.style.top = 0;
  if (tgtRect.right > pRect.right) target.style.left = pRect.width - tgtRect.width + 'px';
  if (tgtRect.bottom > pRect.bottom) target.style.top = pRect.height - tgtRect.height + 'px';
});
```

CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Titillium+Web&display=swap');

body img {
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;

  max-width: 100%;
  height: 61%;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}

body p {
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;

  margin-top: 5%;
  font-family: Titillium Web;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: white;
}

.border{
  height: 98vh; 
  max-width: 100%; 
  border: 1px solid rgba(223, 32, 32, 0.925);
}

.draggable {
  width: 74px;
  height: 104px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
  cursor: move; /* fallback if grab cursor is unsupported */
  cursor: grab;
  cursor: -moz-grab;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
}

.draggable:hover {
  outline: black dotted 2px;
}

.draggable.dragging {
  user-select: none;
  cursor: grabbing;
  cursor: -moz-grabbing;
  cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
  outline: black dotted 2px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dragger {
  height: 104px;
}
```

The Issue:

I have **two** draggable HTML elements inside a div ("border"). The first element (the "My Video's" folder) stays perfectly in between the bounds of the border. But the second element (and every other new element I make) seems to be glitching out when you drag it to the top and/or bottom of the border/page. As if the second element created its own invisible border?! The weirdest thing is that when you drag it slowly towards the top of the border/page it will stay there and it seems to work perfectly until you move up your cursor too much. When moved towards the bottom it just jumps outside the border.

Maybe it has to do with the starting positions of the HTML elements? or the cursor position? I don't know anymore, so that's why I came here. Maybe someone has a quick solution for this (probably very small) problem. I don't know anything about JQuery or JQuery UI that's why I tried doing it in pure Javascript.

I really appreciate any help you can provide!

Comment: There seems to be a basic problem that the dragger elements are all given position relative. I think they need to be absolute so the positioning doesn't affect others.

Answer (score 0):

Here is other option, adding a `data-id` attribute in html to identify which element is being dragged then calculate the final `up` or `bottom`.

```js
var x,
  y,
  target = null;

document.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
  var clickedDragger = false;
  for (var i = 0; e.path[i] !== document.body; i++) {
    if (e.path[i].classList.contains("dragger")) {
      clickedDragger = true;
    } else if (clickedDragger && e.path[i].classList.contains("draggable")) {
      target = e.path[i];
      target.classList.add("dragging");
      x = e.clientX - target.style.left.slice(0, -2);
      y = e.clientY - target.style.top.slice(0, -2);
      return;
    }
  }
});

document.addEventListener("mouseup", function () {
  if (target !== null) target.classList.remove("dragging");
  target = null;
});

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
  if (target === null) return;
  target.style.left = e.clientX - x + "px";
  target.style.top = e.clientY - y + "px";
  var pRect = target.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
  var tgtRect = target.getBoundingClientRect();
  if (tgtRect.left < pRect.left) target.style.left = 0;
  if (tgtRect.right > pRect.right)
    target.style.left = pRect.width - tgtRect.width + "px";

  if (tgtRect.top < pRect.top)
    target.style.top = -tgtRect.height * target.dataset.id + "px";

  if (tgtRect.bottom > pRect.bottom)
    target.style.top =
      pRect.height - tgtRect.height - tgtRect.height * target.dataset.id + "px";
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Titillium+Web&display=swap");

body img {
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;

  max-width: 100%;
  height: 61%;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}

body p {
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;

  margin-top: 5%;
  font-family: Titillium Web;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: white;
}

.border {
  height: 98vh;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(223, 32, 32, 0.925);
}

.draggable {
  width: 74px;
  height: 104px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
  cursor: move; /* fallback if grab cursor is unsupported */
  cursor: grab;
  cursor: -moz-grab;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
}

.draggable:hover {
  outline: black dotted 2px;
}

.draggable.dragging {
  user-select: none;
  cursor: grabbing;
  cursor: -moz-grabbing;
  cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
  outline: black dotted 2px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dragger {
  height: 104px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>Thomas' Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/console favicon.png" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="border">
      <div
        class="draggable"
        ondblclick="location.href='videos.html';"
        data-id="0"
      >
        <div class="dragger">
          <img
            src="https://64.media.tumblr.com/3c645dd8a0ef3647d4e7cd76564b2136/ff2e44bf204fefea-47/s540x810/3b2c927cf2ce25f62ca2ed7aae557c4237b307bc.png"
            width="72"
            height="72"
          />
          <p>My Video's</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div
        class="draggable"
        ondblclick="location.href='photography.html';"
        data-id="1"
      >
        <div class="dragger">
          <img
            src="https://64.media.tumblr.com/e584e0ec79ebc8df9656fa35630208b6/59c7a5fc54f06fab-20/s540x810/c8a1a609f9b5839e3e665faf9b6288c18d55245c.png"
            width="74"
            height="72"
          />
          <p>image.jpg</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```